# Foreach loop : Exclude displayed value

Tags: php, foreach

I have an ARRAY with 15 images, wants to create 5 slides with those 15 images, means 2-3 images per slide (depends on $mode variable).

```
<?php  
 $i = 1;
  for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) { // this for loop is for creating 5 slides
                 if($i % 3 == 0){
                 $CssClass = 'three_slide';
                 $mode = 3;
            }
            else if($i % 3 == 1){
                $CssClass = ' 2 two_slide'; 
                $mode = 2;
            }
            else if($i % 3 == 2){
                $CssClass = ' 3 three_slide_flip';
                $mode = 3;
            }



        ?>
          <div class="arch-slider-item  <?php echo $CssClass; ?>">
              <?php 
                foreach( $images as $image_id ){
                    if($i <= $modRe){ ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id);?>">

                    <?php 
                        } 
                    $i++
                    }
                ?>
         </div>

        <?php 

        } 
?>
```

Issue is, every slide having SAME images, so images from previous slide should be excluded in next slide so that every slide has unique images.

Comment: It's pretty clear that this code will spit out the first two images on the first loop, and increment to `$i` to 16. On the subsequent passes, you won't get any images because that's greater than `$mode`, and `$i` just keeps incrementing.
What's not clear is exactly what you're trying to get. If you have fifteen images, it would be three per slide, unless you're trying for some pattern of the CSS classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php  
// Reformatted code and displayed the numbers, please make necessary changes to make this work with your requirements.
 $i = 1;

 $images = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
 var_dump($images);
 $modRe = 0;
 $current_index = 0;

for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) { // this for loop is for creating 5 slides
  if($i % 3 == 0){
    $CssClass = 'three_slide';
    $mode = 3;
  }
  else if($i % 3 == 1){
    $CssClass = ' 2 two_slide'; 
    $mode = 2;
  }
  else if($i % 3 == 2){
    $CssClass = ' 3 three_slide_flip';
    $mode = 3;
  }
?>
  <div class="arch-slider-item  <?php echo $CssClass; ?>">
    <?php      
      var_dump('Index I = '.$i); // Check the i looping value
      var_dump('Mode = '.$mode);  // Check the mode - having how much images in this slide
      $limit = $current_index+$mode;
      for($index = $current_index; $index < $limit; $index++) {
        if(isset($images[$index])) {
          echo $images[$index]; // Replace code here with your, having single slide and multiple images
        }
        $current_index++;        
      }
      echo "<br>"; // Break the slide
      ?>
  </div>

<?php 
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Well, it worked like a charm mate, Thank you so much @dipak.  I ll spend sometime to dig into this how you did it conceptually but it solved it : )